# Contains a virus and will be deleted

Tags: windows, malware

I fixed someone's laptop recently and found a malware infection.

It's all gone now and all tools show the computer is free of viruses and malware.

However, when downloading a file in internet explorer, it still says that the file contains a virus and will be deleted.
Downloading the same file in Chrome or Firefox works fine.

Microsoft Security Essentials was installed before and seems to have been corrupted by the infection. I assume this is what's blocking in IE. I have done a manual uninstall of MSE but the issue remains.

What else can I try?

Comment: Scan your disk with an anti-malware, example: **Malware-Bytes**.

Comment: What file are you downloading? Perhaps MSE is right.

Comment: a selective backup and full rebuild is indicated.

Comment: take a look at the answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/a/602269/19943)

Answer (score 0):

Do an offline scan. Kasperky's Rescue Disk is one such tool. It discovered (and deleted) a rootkit in the boot sector of a system I recently worked on.

Answer (score 0):

I had very good success with Sophos freeware tools: http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools.aspx

It does a deep scan and also finds and fixes (as much as can be fixed) a rootkit. If you have a Windows rootkit virus, it is recommended by many knowledgeable people that you re-install the OS

Answer (score 0):

Download the file, then upload it to www.virustotal.com to see what most antivirus vendors say about it. Could be a false positive.

Also, your statement that the malware is gone is dubious - it depends on how you 'fixed' the laptop, what malware was detected, and what these 'all tools' are. Did you do e.g. a rootkit scan from a boot CD?

And if your assumption "Microsoft Security Essentials [...] seems to have been corrupted by the infection" is correct: did you completely remove and re-install it?

Comment: "I have done a manual uninstall of MSE but the issue remains." Looks like he has.